# Data loss when storing contacts in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to store the user contacts on Parse.com dashboard. I run my project again & again to store contacts.

But everytime I see different number of contacts stored, some of the contacts(data ie friend & phone no) have been lost.

I am using all this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ParseObject testObject;
EditText et;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.initialize(this, "2dSVesLx7lUKxhSb7B4bSmAOlIVAWONM8sIQTtZb", "CkikNpzXV2eR0QugHnZCQoQjbh6IDgHrESG0KIBS");
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


    et.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // TODO do something
                handled = true;
                testObject = new ParseObject("India"+et.getText().toString());
                readDistinctContacts("India"+et.getText().toString());
//                  readContacts();
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
    
  
}
 public void readDistinctContacts(String s) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        ArrayList<ParseObject> contacts = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) == 1) {
                    System.out.println(name);
                    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject(s);

                    testObject.put("names", name);

                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        System.out.println(phone);
                        testObject.put("phonenumber", phone);
                        if(!list.contains(phone)) {
                            contacts.add(testObject);
                        }

                        list.add(phone);

                    }

                    pCur.close();
                    testObject.saveInBackground();
                }
            }
        }
        cur.close();
    }
  public void readContacts(){
         ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
         Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

         if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) ==1) {
                    System.out.println(name );
                    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("India"+et.getText().toString());

                    testObject.put("names", name);
//                      testObject.saveInBackground();

                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                           new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                          String phone = pCur.getString(
                                 pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                         System.out.println( phone);
                        testObject.put("phonenumber", phone);

                    }
                    pCur.close();
                    testObject.saveInBackground();
                }
            }
       }
    
  }
}
```

I have used both the methods like in code `readcontacts()`, `readDistinctContacts()` , but both are giving me the same problem. Look at the snapshot of my dashboard, it shows different number of contacts every time
[image]

Any solution to manage this problem?

Thanks in advance

## UPDATE

Thanks to askoka, Using [saveEventually()](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveEventually()) there was no data loss but it takes 3-4 minutes to store 400 parseobjects(ie. *contacts*) by 400 push request!. I want the storage should be fast and efficient, can anyone please tell me the best way to make it happen?

Comment: Can you add `System.out.println(cur.getCount());` after you create the variable and see if that always results in the same amount of contacts?

Comment: Yes the same amount of contacts 712 ! And I also get this warning in logcat : Cursor finalized without prior close()

Comment: Yes the same amount of contacts 712 ! And I also get this warning : Cursor finalized without prior close()

Comment: You close pcur, but you don't close cur. That will probably take care of the warning.

Comment: Thanks, for removing this warning but the original problem is still not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `saveInBackground`might be experiencing problems, try passing in a callback to see if there is an error.

```
saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e != null) Log.e("ParseAPITest", "saveInBackground failed: " + e.toString());
    }
});
```

and implement retry logic on your own or you can try :

- replacing `saveInBackground` [with `saveEventually`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveEventually()), which will retry if there is an error in message push.
- batch your push messages by saving all the ParseObjects in a List [and use `saveAllInBackground` preferably with callback](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveAllInBackground(java.util.List)), this will [try to batch your push requests as discussed in `saveAll`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveAll(java.util.List))
- if your app use-case allows, you can create just one `ParseObject` and  add all contacts to this single `ParseObject` and call [`saveEventually`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveEventually()) - this should only take one push request message to parse server, so the delay will be reduced.

  - In your `readDistinctContacts` function you already have `contacts ArrayList`, in which you save each contact as a `ParseObject`. You just need to save that list into one root `ParseObject` and call `saveEventually()` on it - this would result in just one request to the parse server.

    - Just before the `while` loop add `ParseObject root = new ParseObject(s);` and inside the while loop replace `ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject(s);` with `ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Contact" + counter);`. Get rid of `testObject.saveInBackground();`.

      Finally add `root.addAll(root.getClassName(), contacts);root.saveEventually();` after while loop. This should save all your contacts in one go (request), and `saveEventually` will handle any retries needed.

Comment: I am getting a problem that I discusses in chat please visit there http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62389/discussion-between-ashoke-and-vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw

Comment: found the problem, we cannot use space in class name. Remove the space in "Contact " string in `ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Contact" + counter++);`

Comment: still getting this prob https://www.parse.com/questions/eparsecommandcache-saveeventually-thread-had-an-error

Comment: please see my msg in chat. I had to first delete the app on device, before i could try again, as it seems retrying. It works for me with same code, but in my case i only have ~24 contacts. In your code can you `if (counter == 20) break;` and see if it works ?

Comment: Thanks but Still, it takes 3-5 minutes to store 400 contacts

Comment: how much size is your 400 contacts ? depending on your phone network speed, just transferring the data to parse servers could incur delay. And we are only doing one request to parse server.

Comment: according to speedtest.net my download speed is 92kbps, & upload speed is 50kbps

Comment: Perfromance section in parse is also showing 0 to  1.88 request per second

Comment: Storing 400 parseobjects, with 1 push request is **equal to** storing 400 parseobjects with 400 push requests ? Am I right

Comment: well, technically we put all those ParseObjects into ONE ParseObject. So its just one ParseObject we are trying to save. The internals of `saveEventually` may decide how to handle it, for which we dont have code. Just for testing, try replacing `saveEventually` with `saveInBackground` , and also [just `save` directly](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#save()) and compare their performance.

Comment: In either case, we did resolve your **Data loss problem**, the original question, i hope it helped. Performance is always tricky as it involves the device you use, network speed, parse library calls and their performance, parse server itself etc.etc.

Comment: I tried save(), it stores data in less than 20 seconds, with no data loss, but it doesn't retry when the network is again available, all the 3 terms are clear to me ! thanks for you time...

Comment: thats interesting, i guess its better we implement a simple retry logic than rely on parse libraries `saveEventually`